# Is there not a single alt key code combination for adding accents to Spanish characters?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, alt-code

So I need to write occasionally in Spanish.  I *was* using a Spanish keyboard and this had a specific accent key which when pressed appeared to do nothing.  However if you followed that key stroke by pressing e, u, a etc then the letter just typed would appear as a single accented version of the same character!

Now I don't have access to this keyboard so am stuck on a keyboard within the ability to quickly write letters using the accents.

I know I could use a virtual keyboard or learn all the alt+xxx key combinations for individual accented letters but I´m hoping there is a way to access this key that I was pressing on the old keyboard.

Is this assumption wrong and if not what is the combination because whenever I search online for this I just find a whole list of all the individual key codes for each accented letter and I don't really want to try and memorise them all individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to the Extended keyboards.

[For Windows 10] Check your Region and language settings : Select the language in the list : Options button : Add a keyboard : United Kingdom Extended : Optionally remove the normal UK one.

You can then use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) as follows:

- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> `<vowel>` → éíóú, etc
- <kbd>`</kbd> `<vowel>` → è, etc
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> `<vowel>` → ê, etc
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> `<vowel>` → ë, etc
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> `<character>` → ñ, etc

Windows 7 has a similar way of accessing the keyboards via the control panel.